# CustomCursorAdapter does not work with LoaderFramework

Tags: android, android-listfragment, custom-adapter, android-cursorloader

My CursorAdapter loads when I use the `managedQuery` but not when I use the `LoaderFramework`.It loads a blank screen.
The code of my ListFragment:

```
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    adapter=new ContactsAdapter(getActivity(),null);
    setEmptyText("No Contacts found");
    setListShown(false);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_CODE, null, this);
}
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] projections=new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY};
    String orderBy=ContactsContract.Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED+" DESC LIMIT 5";
    CursorLoader loader=new CursorLoader(getActivity(),ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,projections,null,null,orderBy);
    return loader;
}
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    adapter.swapCursor(c);
    if(isResumed())
        setListShown(true);
}
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

My adapter's `newView` and `bindView` methods look like this:

```
        @Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String nameColumn;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    {
        nameColumn=ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY;
    }
    else
    {
        nameColumn=ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
    }
    QuickContactBadge badge=(QuickContactBadge)view.getTag(R.id.rowbadger);
    TextView text_name=(TextView)view.getTag(R.id.text_name);
    TextView text_phone=(TextView)view.getTag(R.id.text_phone);
    long id=c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    Uri lookupUri=Contacts.getLookupUri(id,c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY)));
    badge.assignContactUri(lookupUri);
    Bitmap bitmap=loadContactPhoto(context.getContentResolver(), id);
    badge.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    text_name.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(nameColumn)));
    text_phone.setText(getContactPhoneNumber(id));
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row, parent,false);
    v.setTag(R.id.rowbadger,v.findViewById(R.id.rowbadger));
    v.setTag(R.id.text_name,v.findViewById(R.id.text_name));
    v.setTag(R.id.text_phone,v.findViewById(R.id.text_phone));
    return v;
}
```